# Customizing number of columns in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

### Update:

For anyone who happens upon this question:  This issue seems to have been resolved in a subsequent update to Bootstrap.  You can now download a custom Bootstrap 3 build, specifying the number of desired columns with the `@grid-columns` setting.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

### Original Question:

I'm trying to customize the Bootstrap 3 grid system to use 24 columns rather than the default 12.

As recommended in a number of answers here, I'm attempting to customize the assets using Bootstrap's "Customize and Download" page by modifying the **@gridColumns**, **@gridColumnWidth**, and **@gridGutterWidth** variables.

But Bootstrap 3 seems to have done away with those variables:

- Bootstrap 3 customization page (e.g., no @gridColumns):
  http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
- Bootstrap 2 customization page (e.g., @gridColumns option available):
  http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html

What would be the recommended way of achieving this in Bootstrap 3?  Many thanks!

Comment: Download the latest version from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/master.zip and compile your own version. variables.less defines @grid-columns, so you could change it here. Also post a issue on  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues and ask where the `@gridColumns` setting has gone

Comment: Thanks, Bass.  I'm trying to work through this on a Windows machine.  So I need to install NPM and Node.js to compile the the files in the `bootstrap-master/less/` directory?

Comment: sorry i do know nothing about Windows. The README tells you: "1. Install `grunt-cli` globally with `npm install -g grunt-cli`.
2. Navigate to the root `/bootstrap` directory, then run `npm install`. npm will look at [package.json](package.json) and automatically install the necessary local dependencies listed there." After this run `grunt dist` to compile the js and css only.

Comment: Oh man, okay, compiling bootstrap might be deeper waters than I want to wade into right now just to override a few variable definitions. Going to give up for now and hopefully get back to it later. Thanks for getting me started.

Comment: if you send me an email, i will send you a compiled version with 24 columns

Comment: @tino: can it be placed as per the breakpoint for e.g. in mobile  `$grid-columns` =4 and in desktop should be 12?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The customizer for Twitter's Bootstrap 3.0.0 don't have a option the set the number of grid columns. It will be planned for the next release 3.0.1, see: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10985

Also when you download the latest version from github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/master.zip and compile your own version. <strike>setting @grid-columns in variables.less won't be enough. The class names of the grid columns are hard coded in grid.less, you will have to change / add these too. See also: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10990</strike>

Grid columns are defined dynamically with mixins in grid.less now. You can change `@grid-columns` to any number and recompile.

Comment: This isn't correct, with Bootstrap 3.0.0 you can go ahead and change `@grid-columns` if you'd like, but the columns 1-12 are hardcoded into `grid.less` All you will be doing is changing the width of columns 1-11, 12 will still be 100%, and you won't have 13-24.

Comment: @PaulEnglish donwload the lastes version from github will fix this problem. grid.less has been changed and columns are not hardcoded any more.

Answer (score 1):

This will set 24 columns if you're compiling the bootstrap LESS yourself. Remember that the `@grid-gutter-width` has to be in `px`, `em` units won't work.

`@grid-gutter-width: 14px;`
`@grid-columns: 24;`

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out http://tmaiaroto.github.io/gridline/

... I write more details about why you would want to use it in my blog post, http://www.shift8creative.com/posts/view/flexible-twitter-bootstrap-grid in case you were curious.

To put it short and sweet...You don't want to alter Twitter Bootstrap because it's a project that updates with enough frequency that you're going to get annoyed making your edits all the time.

This is good practice in general for open source projects -- If there is anything you can do over top of them in a non-destructive and non-invasive manner, you should prefer to do that first. Your last ditch effort is to alter the source of the project.

Comment: Alternatively you can make a Grunt task to always pull in and alter the grid settings. That would be more convenient than a manual process. Again though, I've found this tiny JavaScript solution far more convenient because you can mix and match your columns (not to mention you can then load from Twitter Bootstrap a CDN).

Answer (score 0):

Late but I built out a solution to this using LESS that doesn't require modification of Bootstrap.
https://github.com/drew-r/bootstrap-n-column

Comment: Does it exist for SASS as well?

Comment: @Bart no sorry - if you come across / develop something equivalent in SASS let me know and I'll link to it from GH.