# Is it possible to set the boostrap columns to 24 in a yo angular-fullstack project?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, yo, angular-fullstack

I have a fairly large project underway that was generated using the yo angular-fullstack framework, which I highly recommend.

In the past, I have utilized 24 column settings for bootstrap by customizing the boostrap build.  Is this easy/possible in this case?

The great part of using bower, npm, etc. is that you get a solid framework, but it is now not clear how to replace the bower boostrap piece (which is what I assume I need to do) without breaking things.  Or is it easy to just modify the @grid-columns setting to 24? And how to then rebuild?

I realize that I can download bootstrap and customize. I was hoping that there was an easy way to do this, without uninstalling the bower version using bower and then producing my own version. Is there an easier way to customize the bower version of bootstrap, or is this as silly question?

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customizing number of columns in Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253088/customizing-number-of-columns-in-bootstrap-3)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253088/customizing-number-of-columns-in-bootstrap-3

Comment: I realize that I can download bootstrap and customize.  I was hoping that there was an easy way to do this, without uninstalling the bower version using bower and then producing my own version.  Of is there an easy way to customize the bower version of bootstrap?