# Using decimals in column width for bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, multiple-columns

I couldn't figure out how to make the bootstrap column like this:

col-md-4.5 | col-md-7.5

Comment: well, it's known that it was hardcoded 12 columns. But if you can increase to 24 columns, you don't need the decimals - it would be 9 and 15, right? Look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253088/customizing-number-of-columns-in-bootstrap-3. I'm not sure if they finally implemented this, however it is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

you can use media query

like that you can use media query when screen size change

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { 
    .your-class1{
         width:37.5%;
     }
    .your-class2{
         width:62.5%;
    } 
}


/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

see  http://getbootstrap.com/css/