# How change number of columns in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

How to change a **number of columns in Bootstrap** 4?

```
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customizing number of columns in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253088/customizing-number-of-columns-in-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

EDIT:

It turns out this can be done. Perhaps the most straightforward way is to use a bootstrap "auto layout column" [as mentioned here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns). This is quite intuitive and gets the job done. It'll automatically use as many columns as you've given it.

OLD ANSWER:

Bootstrap uses a standard 12 column layout, and this cannot be changed. The idea is to combine these columns to have a more flexible website design.

For example, if you want 3 columns, you should create elements that each take up 4 columns.

This is how bootstrap was built, and it's the reason that they use the number "12" - it divides neatly by many numbers.

Comment: Actually it's possible to change the column amount using a Sass variable in Bootstrap.

Comment: @MobyMotion there are also [auto-layout columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns) which can exceed 12.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know this, thanks for letting me know. I'm new to stack overflow - should I delete my answer or edit it? Or is that not necessary because people can see these comments

Comment: You can edit it, but remember in the future to [only answer "well-asked" questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).